# Reading pointer data

Tags: c

i'm using a library which has an OpenGL like syntax. When using a function to get data to a pointer, it sometimes brings in the first cells irrelevant numbers.

```
int *rIndices = (int*)malloc(icount * 500* sizeof(int));
giGetIndexedMesh(&vcount, &icount, rIndices);
for (int j = 0; j < icount; j += 3)
{
    printf("%d %d %d\n", rIndices[j], rIndices[j + 1], rIndices[j + 2]);
}
```

And the out put is:

```
-1107141503 1047065916 1058222111
- 1118597697 -1083120598 1041096918
-1118541674 -1082575688 1040872831
-1129197583 -1082576454 1041095778
170 190 135
100 174 172
116 175 184
176 191 178
177 176 178
```

This doesn't happen always. Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

PS the numbers should be like the 5th row and after.
thanks in advance.

Comment: This question needs a reproducible example and more explanation. What is `giGetIndexedMesh` for example?

Comment: This depends on what you do in `giGetIndexedMesh`. Without that code, readers cannot pinpoint your problem.

Comment: It is a function that extracts data from the graphic card into a pointer. I am thinking that it could be a more general problem.

Comment: Information missing. And don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C.

Comment: Please do not tag your question with OpenGL just because you're using a library that copies OpenGL's function style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a quick look at the [documentation](http://opengi.sourceforge.net/doc/group__mesh.html#gac2d6a026c752f1ac9e5aaae95b1db3a4), you should call the function `giGetIndexedMesh` twice. First, to retrieve the required sizes (`vcount` and `icount`) by setting the last parameter to NULL. And the second time to retrieve the indices.

In your code snippet, you allocate the array using an old value of `icount`. The required value is determined later, but you must determine it before:

```
GIuint vcount, icount;
giGetIndexedMesh(&vcount, &icount, NULL);
GIunit *indices = malloc (...);
giGetIndexedMesh(&vcount, &icount, indices);
```

I didn't find enough information on the array layout. Thus, I didn't completed the `malloc` call. You should also check the return value of `malloc` an `giGetIndexedMesh`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin, i'm calling it twice as you say. But sometimes as i'm enabling other attributes i'm getting in the first pointer cells garbage..

Comment: @ionas Garbage data indicates a heap  (or stack) overflow. Check all your function calls whether an array of sufficient size has been passed in. Also always check the return value of the function calls, maybe one of it fails so that the memory stays uninitialized.

Comment: @ionas Moreover, the function returns an array of `GIuint`. These are 4 Byte unsigned integers, not signed `int`s.